# MongoDB - How to select fields conditionally

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I am new to MongoDB. I have a VIEW created on a collection, I need to make a modification to this VIEW.
Say we have a collection **CollectionName**. It has an array field **aArray**. This arrays has 2 fields, **arrayField1** and **arrayField2**. Currently, the fields are being selected from **aArray** as below :

```
$replaceRoot :
{
  newRoot: {
    $mergeObjects: [
      {
        arrayFieldNew1: '$aArray.arrayField1',
        arrayFieldNew1: '$aArray.arrayField2'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, a new array **bArray** is added to the collection. The **bArray** is same as **aArray**. The field names of **bArray** are same as **aArray** which are **arrayField1** and **arrayField2**.I need to select **arrayField1** and **arrayField2** from **aArray**, only if **bArray** is not present. If **bArray** exists then select **arrayField1** and **arrayField2** from **bArray**.

I hope I am able to communicate my requirement.

I have tried googling this problem but didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using [$cond](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#-cond--aggregation-) and [$type](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/#-type--aggregation-) for each field, such as:

```
        arrayFieldNew1: {$cond:{
                   if: {$eq:[{$type:"$bArray"},'missing']},
                   then: '$aArray.arrayField1',
                   else: '$bArray.arrayField1'
        }}
```

Comment: Nailed it, Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditionals to solve this. A suitable one is `$ifNull`.

See demo at https://runkit.com/embed/jatnkig9hbye

```js
db.collection.insertMany([
  {
    aArray: {
      arrayField1: "A"
    },
    bArray: {
      arrayField2: "B"
    }
  }
])

const res = db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "arrayField1": {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$bArray.arrayField1", // check bArray first
          "$aArray.arrayField1"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

console.log(res) // [{"arrayField1": "A"}]
```